# Custom tiles yet geo accurate in LeafletJS

Tags: leaflet

I'm interested in custom map tiles, and using advice from [here](https://github.com/rktjmp/tileup) and [here](http://omarriott.com/aux/leaflet-js-non-geographical-imagery/), I've experimented with exactly that. For a prototype I did a very geeky map of the Star Trek Federation, with episode links moving you around the planets/systems etc.

While that's all fine and dandy for fantastical locations, I'd also be interested in using heavily stylised renditions of real world locations, yet still using real `lat,lng` points. So, for example, a bespoke, yet mostly geo accurate, map of London, chopped into tiles, but if you passed in `lat,lng` coords for Camden Tube (`51.53911 -0.14235`), you would move to that location.

Any ideas how you configure LeafletJS to do this, without going the route of using Google Maps with custom tiles?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have 2 different applications:

- Your Star Trek map, for which you are satisfied.
- Stylised map of real world, for which you would like real `lat,lng` coordinates to be accurate?

Then your question is how to create your custom tiles, so that Leaflet shows the stylised view of London when passed the real London coordinates?

In that case, it would be probably just a matter of correctly numbering your tiles. Or the reverse, modifying the tile numbers used by Leaflet to build the tiles URL. For the latter solution, see [Specifying Lat & Long for Leaflet TileLayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33908120/specifying-lat-long-for-leaflet-tilelayer)

Comment: I think renaming the tiles is probably the way forward.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "**mostly** geo accurate". It sounds like you probably just want to generate your own map tiles from some kind of source like OpenStreetMap. In that case, TileMill (although kind of obsolete) is probably the easiest way to go.

There are basically three parts:

1. Generate some map tiles (eg TileMill)
2. Host them (eg TileStream)
3. Point Leaflet at them

Comment: Well, it could mean take a screengrab of openstreetmap image of desired area, and use that as the layout for the heavily stylised approach (print to physical canvas, layer with oil paints etc, then scan back in). That's what I meant by "mostly." Sorry if that wasn't clear.