# Create custom map in Leaflet with coordinates

Tags: leaflet

I have a historical city map that I want to display using Leaflet. 
I like to set the coordinates of this image to reflect the real world, e.g so I can click on the image and get the real coordinates.

I guess I can just make it an overlay to a real map, but there must be a better solution just define at what coordinates of the corners of the image.

For this image, the approx real world coordinates is NW: 60.34343, 18.43360, SE: 60.33761, 18.44819

My code, so far, is here: 
http://stage1876.xn--regrund-80a.se/example3.html

Any ideas how to proceed? It feels like it there should be an easy way to do this?

Any help would be so appreciated!

EDIT: The implementation (so far) with tiles are optional. I could go for a one image-map as well.

Comment: You should mention first that your current implementation shows your map as tiles through zoomify.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33908120/specifying-lat-long-for-leaflet-tilelayer

Comment: @ghybs True. I'm using tiles, but that part of my implementation is optional. A one-image-solution would be as good, as long as I could geoposition it.

Comment: Then use an [`L.imageOverlay`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#imageoverlay) with the correct coordinates as bounds, it will be way more simple to begin with.