# Leaflet - How to display a smaller map inside a larger map (with tiles)?

Tags: leaflet

I have the following problem: I have a world map, which should serve as a base map and a map of a certain region (e.g. Germany). Both are available in tile format. I would like to display the regional map above the world map at the correct coordinate position. And here's the problem: I can display the region map above the world map, but I don't know how to position it correctly.

Anybody got any advice here?

**EDIT**

Here I create a simple base map on which I want to display data later. Afterwards I divide the map into tiles with gdal2tiles.py.

```
map = Basemap( projection='merc', resolution='c', 
               lat_0=51., lon_0=10., 
               urcrntlat=85.051, urcrnrlon=179.000, 
               llcrnrlat=85.051, llcrnrlon=-179.000
             )
map.bluemarble()

filename='map.png'
dirname = 'tiles'
plt.savefig ( filename )

minZoom = 0
maxZoom = 4
subprocess.check_output( "gdal2tiles.py --leaflet --profile=raster --zoom=" + str(minZoom) + "-" + str(maxZoom) + " " + filename + " " + dirname,
                         stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                         shell=True,
                       )
```

Here I use the functions from tilenames.py to determine where the tile should be.

```
import tilenames as tn 
for z in range(minZoom, maxZoom):
    x, y = tn.tileXV(lat, lon, z)
    s,w,n,e = tn.tileEdges(x, y, z)

print("z={:d}: x={:d} y={:d} --> urcrnrlat={:.3f}, urcrnrlon={:.3f}, llcrnrlat={:.3f}, llcrnrlat={:.3f}".format(z,x,y,n,e,s,w))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specifying Lat & Long for Leaflet TileLayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33908120/specifying-lat-long-for-leaflet-tilelayer)

Comment: Yes, in fact, it's the same case. I read your solution in the other post. Unfortunately, the right click in OpenStreetMap does not work (anymore), so I cannot display the corresponding tile number. I must admit, I don't understand how I can convert the coordinates for e.g. lat=51 and lon=10 into tile numbers depending on the zoom level?

Comment: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Lon..2Flat._to_tile_numbers

Comment: Thanks! That link was really helpful.

Comment: Well, at least that's what I thought... I now have tilenames.py, which is mentioned in the wiki and determines the tile that should contain my coordinate. But no matter what I do, it's never where it should be. To create the tiles, I use gdal2tiles.py for leaflet with the following command:

gdal2ziles.py --leaftlet --profile=raster --zoom=minZ-maxZ filename dirname

Answer (score 0):

See the [section titled "minimaps and synced maps" in the Leaflet plugins list](http://leafletjs.com/plugins#minimaps--synced-maps).

Sounds like your use case is well covered by some plugins in that list, specifically either [Leaflet.Minimap](https://github.com/Norkart/Leaflet-MiniMap) or [Leaflet.Sync](https://github.com/turban/Leaflet.Sync). Please check the documentation and examples for those, and have a quick look at the other plugins in that list.

Comment: I have. Unfortunately that was not the solution to my problem. Any other suggestions?